# How to add if condition in a TensorFlow graph?

Tags: python, if-statement, tensorflow

Let's say I have following code:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[None, ins_size**2*3], name = "x_input")
condition = tf.placeholder("int32", shape=[1, 1], name = "condition")
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ins_size**2*3,label_option]), name = "weights")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([label_option]), name = "bias")

if condition > 0:
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
else:
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) - b)
```

Would the `if` statement work in the calculation (I do not think so)? If not, how can I add an `if` statement into the TensorFlow calculation graph?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You're correct that the `if` statement doesn't work here, because the condition is evaluated at graph construction time, whereas presumably you want the condition to depend on the value fed to the placeholder at runtime. (In fact, it will always take the first branch, because `condition > 0` evaluates to a `Tensor`, which is ["truthy" in Python](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs258/truthiness-in-python).)

To support conditional control flow, TensorFlow provides the [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#cond) operator, which evaluates one of two branches, depending on a boolean condition. To show you how to use it, I'll rewrite your program so that `condition` is a scalar `tf.int32` value for simplicity:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, ins_size**2*3], name="x_input")
condition = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[], name="condition")
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ins_size**2 * 3, label_option]), name="weights")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([label_option]), name="bias")

y = tf.cond(condition > 0, lambda: tf.matmul(x, W) + b, lambda: tf.matmul(x, W) - b)
```

Comment: @mrry Are both branches executed by default ? I have tf.cond(c, lambda x: train_op1, lambda x: train_op2) and both train_ops are executed at each execution of cond independently of the value of c. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski This is a sometimes surprising behavior of `tf.cond()`, which is touched upon [in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond). In short, you need to create the ops that you want to run conditionally *inside* the respective lambdas. Everything that you create outside the lambdas but refer to in either branch will execute in both cases.

Comment: @mrry Wow, that's rather unexpected :) Thanks for the answer, defining ops inside functions solved the problem.

Comment: Is the condition/( application of the logic) element-wise?

Answer (score 10):

### TensorFlow 2.0

[TF 2.0 introduces a feature called AutoGraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/autograph) which lets you JIT compile python code into Graph executions. This means you can use python control flow statements (yes, this includes `if` statements). From the docs,

> AutoGraph supports common Python statements like `while`, `for`, `if`,
>   `break`, `continue` and `return`, with support for nesting. That means you
>   can use Tensor expressions in the condition of `while` and `if`
>   statements, or iterate over a Tensor in a `for` loop.

You will need to define a function implementing your logic and annotate it with [**`tf.function`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/function). Here is a modified example from the documentation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def sum_even(items):
  s = 0
  for c in items:
    if tf.equal(c % 2, 0): 
        s += c
  return s

sum_even(tf.constant([10, 12, 15, 20]))
#  <tf.Tensor: id=1146, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=42>
```

Comment: Why are you using `tf.equal()`? Shouldn't you be able to use `==` and let AutoGraph compile it automatically?

Comment: @problemofficer That's a gooooood question. I assumed (like you) the same thing but got bitten. Here is a question I asked which discusses this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616485/equality-comparison-does-not-work-inside-tensorflow-2-0-tf-function