# assign values to an array in a loop in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a array of ones in tensorflow and I want to update its values based on another array in a for loop. Here is the code:

```
def get_weights(labels, class_ratio=0.5):
        weights = tf.ones_like(labels, dtype=tf.float64))

        pos_num = class_ratio * 100
        neg_num = 100 - class_ratio * 100
        for i in range(labels.shape[0]):
            if labels[i] == 0:
               weights[i].assign(pos_num/neg_num)
            else:
               weights[i].assign(neg_num)

        return weights
```

an then I have this code to call the above function:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
     labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (5,))
     example_weights = get_weights(labels, class_ratio=0.1)
     with tf.Session() as sess:
          np_labels = np.random.randint(0, 2, 5)
          np_weights = sess.run(example_weights, feed_dict={labels: np_labels})
         print("Labels:  %r" % (np_labels,))
         print("Weights: %r" % (np_weights,))
```

but when I run it, it gives me this error:

`ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables`

How can I assign/update values of an array in tensorflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) in TensorFlow is a read-only value—in fact, a symbolic expression for computing a read-only value—so you cannot in general assign values to it. (The main exceptions are [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) objects.) This means that you are encourage to use "functional" operations to define your tensor. For example, there are several ways to generate the `weights` tensor functionally:

- Since `weights` is defined as an element-wise transformation of `labels`, you can use [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) to create a new tensor (containing a [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to [replace the `if` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35833133/3574081)) by mapping a function across it:

  ```
  def get_weights(labels, class_ratio=0.5):
    pos_num = tf.constant(class_ratio * 100)
    neg_num = tf.constant(100 - class_ratio * 100)

    def compute_weight(x):
      return tf.cond(tf.equal(x, 0), lambda: pos_num / neg_num, lambda: neg_num)

    return tf.map_fn(compute_weight, labels, dtype=tf.float32)
  ```

  This version allows you to apply an arbitrarily complicated function to each element of `labels`.
- However, since the function is simple, cheap to compute, and representable using simple TensorFlow ops, you can avoid using `tf.map_fn()` and instead use [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):

  ```
  def get_weights(labels, class_ratio=0.5):
    pos_num = tf.fill(tf.shape(labels), class_ratio * 100)
    neg_num = tf.fill(tf.shape(labels), 100 - class_ratio * 100)
    return tf.where(tf.equal(labels, 0), pos_num / neg_num, neg_num)
  ```

  (You could also use `tf.where()` instead of `tf.cond()` in the `tf.map_fn()` version.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! It works perfect!