# tf.reduce_max inconsistent on comparison

Tags: python, if-statement, tensorflow, graph, tensor

Given a list/tensor of items, I want to check whether the max item of the whole list is the same as the max item in specific part of list:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.get_variable('a', (10,100))
b = tf.unstack(a,axis=1)
c = tf.reduce_max(b[0])
d = tf.reduce_max(b[0])
if c == d:
  c = tf.ones((1,100))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run([c,d])
```

In the above example, `c` and `d` should be the same, however, when you run the model, it doesn't satisfy the condition to re-make variable `c` as a one vector. This is just an example to show that these types of comparison seem to be wrong. Any idea what would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

> in the above example, c and d should be the same

No. You should be careful here. `c` and `d` are different ops in a *computational graph*. Comparing them with `==` is pointless, they are always different objects. What you're really looking for is [`tf.equal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal) to determine if the tensor values are the same element-wise and [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to organize an `if` statement in a computational graph. It would look something like this:

```
result = tf.cond(tf.equal(c, d), lambda: tf.ones((1, 100)), lambda: tf.zeros((1, 100)))
```

Also, note that reassignment of a python variable that points to an op (`c` in this case) *does not* change the op in the graph.

Comment: To follow up on Maxim. [Here][1] is a stackoverflow thread about how to make conditions in tensorflow.
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833011/how-to-add-if-condition-in-a-tensorflow-graph