# Equality comparison does not work inside TensorFlow 2.0 tf.function()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Following the discussion on [TensorFlow 2.0 AutoGraphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/autograph), I've been playing around and noticed that inequality comparisons such as `>` and `<` are specified directly, whereas equality comparisons are represented using `tf.equal`.

Here's an example to demonstrate. This function uses `>` operator and **works well** when called:

```
@tf.function
def greater_than_zero(value):
    return value > 0

greater_than_zero(tf.constant(1))
#  <tf.Tensor: id=1377, shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>
greater_than_zero(tf.constant(-1))
# <tf.Tensor: id=1380, shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=False>
```

Here is another function that uses equality comparison, but **does not work**:

```
@tf.function
def equal_to_zero(value):
    return value == 0

equal_to_zero(tf.constant(1))
# <tf.Tensor: id=1389, shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=False>  # OK...

equal_to_zero(tf.constant(0))
# <tf.Tensor: id=1392, shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=False>  # WHAT?
```

If I change the `==` equality comparison to `tf.equal`, it will work.

```
@tf.function
def equal_to_zero2(value):
    return tf.equal(value, 0)

equal_to_zero2(tf.constant(0))
# <tf.Tensor: id=1402, shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>
```

My question is: Why does using inequality comparison operators work inside `tf.function` functions, whereas equality comparisons do not?

Comment: I believe because equality operators in the context of tensors are reserved/used to compare tensor objects and allowing to mix object operators "t1 == t2" and algebraic operators "t1 == 0" would lead to a lot of confusion. To be fair, TF always incentivized using operators explicitly like tf.greater_then, tf.add and support for overloaded mathematical operators are mostly just for convenience.

Comment: AFAIK `==` for tensors actually checks whether they are the _same object_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I analyzed this behavior in part 3 of the article ["Analysing tf.function to discover Autograph strengths and subtleties"](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/05/10/dissecting-tf-function-part-3/) (and I highly recommend reading all the 3 parts to understand how to correctly write a function before decorating it with `tf.function` - links at the bottom of the answer).

For the `__eq__` and `tf.equal` question, the answer is:

> In short: the `__eq__` operator (for `tf.Tensor`) has been overridden, but the operator does not use `tf.equal` to check for the Tensor equality, it just checks for the Python variable identity (if you are familiar with the Java programming language, this is precisely like the == operator used on string objects). The reason is that the `tf.Tensor` object needs to be hashable since it is used everywhere in the Tensorflow codebase as key for dict objects.

While for all the other operators, the answer is that AutoGraph doesn't convert Python operators to TensorFlow logical operators. In the section [How AutoGraph (don’t) converts the operators](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/05/10/dissecting-tf-function-part-3/#lesson-2-how-autograph-dont-converts-the-operators) I showed that every Python operator gets converted to a graph representation that is always evaluated as false.

In fact, the following example produces as output "wat"

```py
@tf.function
def if_elif(a, b):
  if a > b:
    tf.print("a > b", a, b)
  elif a == b:
    tf.print("a == b", a, b)
  elif a < b:
    tf.print("a < b", a, b)
  else:
    tf.print("wat")
x = tf.constant(1)
if_elif(x,x)
```

In practice, AutoGraph is unable to convert Python code to graph code; we have to help it using only the TensorFlow primitives. In that case, your code will work as you expect.

```py
@tf.function
def if_elif(a, b):
  if tf.math.greater(a, b):
    tf.print("a > b", a, b)
  elif tf.math.equal(a, b):
    tf.print("a == b", a, b)
  elif tf.math.less(a, b):
    tf.print("a < b", a, b)
  else:
    tf.print("wat")
```

I let here the links to all the three articles, I guess you'll find them usefult:

[part 1](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/), [part 2](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/04/03/dissecting-tf-function-part-2/), [part 3](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/05/10/dissecting-tf-function-part-3/)

Comment: Money line: "In practice, AutoGraph is unable to convert Python code to graph code; we have to help it using only the TensorFlow primitives." Will read thru the articles as well, looks quite informative. Thanks!

Comment: Off topic, and you probably get this often, but your knowledge in TensorFlow is solid. I'm heading into a line of work where I'll need to become good (and I mean really good) at it myself. If I may ask, what was your learning process, and did answering questions on Stack Overflow contribute to your overall wealth of TensorFlow knowledge? Appreciate any advice you could spare for a green bean :)

Comment: @cs95 I learned TensorFlow by solving problems. When I was a research fellow, I have to learn by myself how to do object classification and localization. At that time (it was the end of 2015) tf was something new, and I spent a lot of time learning it, always with the goal of solving that task. Then, once I became a little bit more confident with the high-level API (and I solved my research problem) I started answering on SO to check if my understanding of the framework structure was correct - it helped a lot, and I highly recommend doing it. In short, have a goal, use tf to solve it and learn

Comment: @nessuno - I'm sorry but this is *wrong*, at least in tf 2.7. I copy pasted your code and it does NOT print `wat`. Please take a look: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eGpiOWO_OwggHoOoTvx_jdeCU8jqJzHy?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @ihadanny! Yes, right now they fixed this behavior luckily. When I wrote the article, the talks, and this answer, there still was this huge problem going on.

Comment: @nessuno - thanks for the clarification! then can you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332161/tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-using-tf-greater-and-simply-greater ?