# tensorflow: what is the difference between using tf.greater and simply greater?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to understand the difference between these two functions, as far as the generated tf graph goes:

```
def simple_relu(x):
  if tf.greater(x, 0):
    return x
  else:
    return 0
```

and

```
def simple_relu2(x):
  if x > 0:
    return x
  else:
    return 0
```

I executed `autograph.to_code` on both, and got this diff:

```
ag__.if_stmt(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).greater, (ag__.ld(x), 0), None, fscope)
```

and

```
ag__.if_stmt((ag__.ld(x) > 0)
```

What does it mean? how will that affect tracing or graph execution?

(related to [Equality comparison does not work inside TensorFlow 2.0 tf.function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616485/equality-comparison-does-not-work-inside-tensorflow-2-0-tf-function) where the answer is just wrong)

Answer (score 2):

There must be no difference between `x > y` and `tf.greater(x, y)` inside `tf.function`. However, when you are using `if x > 0: ... else ...` statement inside `tf.fucntion` is not clear what you mean. In particular, `x` can be not a rank 0 tensor...

1. If you wish to do an element-wise operation use

`tf.max(0, x)`.

2. If you want to make an element-wise selection use

`tf.where(x > 0, tensor1, tensor2)`.

provided `x`, `tensor1` and `tensor2` are of the same (broadcastable) shapes.

3. If `x` is a scalar you can use

`tf.cond(x > 0, lambda: f1(tensors), lambda: f2(tensors))`.

Thus, exactly one of the operations `f1(tensors)` and `f2(tensors)` is executed.

I suggest to do not use pythonic `if` and `for` inside `tf.function` at all because is not clear how it is compiled to graph operations `tf.cond` and `tf.while_loop`. Use `tf.where`, `tf.cond` or `tf.switch_case` directly according to your needs.

The answer [Equality comparison does not work inside TensorFlow 2.0 tf.function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616485/equality-comparison-does-not-work-inside-tensorflow-2-0-tf-function)
looks correct.