# Using conditional expressions for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have tensor x and i want to compare this tensor with tensor y. But when i wrote:

```
def f(x, n, P):
            y_1 = tf.constant([n / P], dtype=tf.float64)
            y_2 = tf.constant([(n - 1) / P], dtype=tf.float64)
            y_3 = tf.constant([(n + 1) / P], dtype=tf.float64)

            y = 0
            if tf.math.greater_equal(x, y_1) == True and tf.math.greater_equal(y_3, x) == True:
                y = -x * P
            elif tf.math.greater_equal(x, y_2) == True and tf.math.greater(y_1, x) == True:
                y = x * P
            return tf.dtypes.cast(y, dtype=tf.float64)
```

It does not work properly. How can I use condition expession with tensors?
Then I updated my code:

```
        def f1(x, n, P):
            return tf.dtypes.cast(n + 1 - x * P, dtype=tf.float64)

        def f2(x, n, P):
            return tf.dtypes.cast(1 - n + x * P, dtype=tf.float64)

        def f3(x, n, P):
            return tf.dtypes.cast(tf.constant([0]), dtype=tf.float64)

        def fl_not_1(x, n, P, y_2, y_1):
            tf.cond(y_2 <= x and x < y_1, f2, f3)



        def f(x, n, P):   
            y_1 = tf.constant(n / P, shape=[1, 1], dtype=tf.float64)
            y_2 = tf.constant((n - 1) / P, shape=[1, 1], dtype=tf.float64)
            y_3 = tf.constant((n + 1) / P, shape=[1, 1], dtype=tf.float64)

            y = tf.cond(y_1 <= x and x <= y_3, f1, f_not_1)
            return tf.dtypes.cast(y, dtype=tf.float64)
```

But i got follow error: TypeError: Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add if condition in a TensorFlow graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833011/how-to-add-if-condition-in-a-tensorflow-graph)

Comment: I tried to solve my problem with the help of this link but i got follow error: TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: Ok, I updated. I just wanted to use tf.cond, but unfortunately It doesn't help me. Maybe I use tf.cond() not right

Answer (score 0):

Please use the combination of **tf.cond** and **tf.math** libraries like **tf.greater**, **tf.greater_equal** - instead of using **'>,='** **operators** because **tensors** does not work with **python bool** operators.