# Tensorflow: If statement with tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to check if the tensorflow tensor `rand_int=0` in an if statement. In the below code, the if statement is not executed when rand_int=0.

```
rand_int = tf.random.uniform((), 0, 2, dtype=tf.int32)
if rand_int == 0:
    # Lots of lines of code
    ...
```

However, in the below code, the if statement is executed.

```
rand_int = tf.random.uniform((), 0, 2, dtype=tf.int32)
rand_int = tf.Session().run(rand_int)
if rand_int == 0:
    ...
```

How would I execute the if statement in the first block without `tf.Session()`?

Comment: In the first snippet, `rand_int` is a `Tensor` type object which will not equal `0` or `1`. That's probably why the contents of the `if`'s true branch are not executed. In the second snippet, `rand_int` is redefined as the output of `session.run()` and will either be `0` or `1`. So, the contents of the `if`'s true branch may execute with 50% probability.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I would like to know if there is a way to do an if statement in tensorflow that allows for the first snippet.

Comment: Interesting. I've not come across this use case yet. I think defining tensorflow constants like `one = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32)` and `zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)` may be useful. Since `one` and `zero` are also tensors, `is_zero = rand_int == zero` will also be a tensor. However, we may still not be able to execute `if is_zero` as expected. We will need something like `tf.cond` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833011/how-to-add-if-condition-in-a-tensorflow-graph

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using session if you switch to TensorFlow (TF) 2.X version.
TF 2 uses eager execution by default therefore you don't need Session to execute your graph. Moreover the contents of tensor are evaluated at runtime and can be accessed.
Following code is tested with recent stable TF 2.4.0 version.

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
rand_int = tf.random.uniform((), 0, 2, dtype=tf.int32)
#rand_int = tf.compat.v1.Session().run(rand_int)
if rand_int == 0:
    print('Inside If Block')

#Output:
Inside If Block
```